# How to append HTML only to the current element slected by class

Tags: jquery, html

In my real case scenario I have four `<table>` objects in my table which are inside `<div>` with `style="display: none"` like so "

```
<div id="person-info-table" style="display: none">
    <hr />
    <div>Personal info</div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="personInfoGrid">
    //..


<div id="associates-table" style="display: none">
    <div>Associates info</div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="associatesGrid">
    //..
```

and so on.

Under certain conditions I want to load this table and show it which i made with separate `Ajax` call for each table:

```
 success: function (data) {
              if (data > 0) {
                  $("#person-info-table").show();
                  $('#personInfoGrid').MydataTable();
              }
          }
```

Here I am using my own extension of the `jquery DataTable` but I don't think it makes any difference to the problem I have. For each new `DataTable` I add a custom `Clear filters` button like so:

```
$('.dataTables_length').append("<button class='btnClearFilter' onclick='..'>Clear</button>");
```

However when I have more than one table loaded, for example 3 the final result is that the first table has 3 buttons `|Clear| |Clear| |Clear|` the second table `|Clear| |Clear|` and the las `|Clear|` only one. I tried to recreate as much as possible what I'm getting right now in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h6dtat0/) example. In my original code I tried to get the current element that I'm working with like so:

```
$($(this.selector).find(".dataTables_length")).append(--My HTML--);
```

which doesn't produce error in the console but I don't get anything rendered on neither table too. I tried various ways to try and append the desired `HTML` only to the current element that I'm working with since it seems to me that this is the problem(ant the solution) but I can't find way to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you showed in your example, you're using:

```
$('#parent').append('<div class="active"></div>');
$('div.active').append('<button>New Button</button>');
```

You're appending all elements div elements with class active, so as you add more elements to the DOM, JQuery is performing your function on more elements.

Use something like this:

```
var table = $('#person-info-table').find('table');

initialise($table);

function initialise($table){

$(table).find('.dataTables_length').append("<button class='btnClearFilter' ...

}
```

Comment: is it `$` typo in `initialise($table);` because if I try like this I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $table is not defined` but if I remove the `$` sign, I don't get error but still no button is rendered.

Comment: P.S it was problem in my current code. The table is actually child of the `<div>` so I hade to add `.parent().find()..` and it's working. Thanks.